# Array Division Linear Least lstsq gives wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I'm practicing matrix division, in Python using a non-square matrix. Starting with a 4 by 1 column vector (E) and a 1 by 3 row vector (S) I multiply these together using outer to generate Matrix (A). Then I attempt to use Linear Least Squares from linear algebra to obtain A1 from E and S and E1 from A and S but get the wrong result...

Linear Algebra: Linear Least Squares and Linear Algebra Solve (doesn't work for non-square matrices).

Python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
E=np.array([[1],[5],[4],[2]])
S=np.array([3,5,4])
A=np.array([[3,5,4],[15,25,20],[12,20,16],[6,10,8]])
A1=np.outer(E,S)
print(A1)
[S1,resid,rank,s] =np.linalg.lstsq(A,E,rcond=None)
print(S1)
[E1t,resid,rank,s] =np.linalg.lstsq(A.T,S.T,rcond=None)
print(E1t)
E1=E1t.T
print(E1)
```

MATLAB

```
E=[1;5;1;2]
S=[3,5,4]
A=E*S
E1=A/S
A1=E\A
```

For A1 this yields a vector which is a correct ratio but a factor of 50 out... [0.06 0.1  0.08] opposed to [3,5,4] and for E1 [0.02173913 0.10869565 0.08695652 0.04347826] opposed to [1,5,4,2] which is again of the correct ratio but a factor of 46 out. I am comparing this to MATLAB's left and right division which yields the correct result.

Comment: One of your rows is duplicated for both S and A which means you have a degenerate matrix. Your solution will not be unique and hence the scaling factor. This would explain why you're seeing different solutions between the two environments. Try substituting a unique row for both the matrices to replace one of the duplicated rows and run the code again.

Comment: You haven't specified `E` correctly.  To match your matlab representation, it should be `E = np.array([[1], [5], [1] , [2]])`.

Comment: I believe `E*S=A` isn't a correct assignment either ...

Comment: I have corrected the format of the column vector in the Python code and reassigned A=E*S in the MATLAB code and have made the values in E and hence A unique. It still gives the main problem however.

Comment: Each row in A is a scalar multiple of the first row. It's still degenerate.